# Dajaxice with Class Based View

Tags: python, django, dajaxice, django-class-based-views

Is there a way to user dajaxice with django class based views?
I'm trying this, but not having much success:

```
class FavoriteEnroledTrainee(SessionMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'here'

    @method_decorator(dajaxice_register(method='GET', name='company.favorite'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(FavoriteEnroledTrainee, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

I can see the dajaxice is able to fetch the view but nothing gets printed.

Comment: Have you tried return an `HttpResponse` instead of `print`?

Comment: yes, i did, no success as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot register the dispatch method, because it's not the view entry point. Dajaxice will try to call dispatch directly, but this won't work because it's not a fully functionnal view.

You should register the result of the *as_view* call :

```
class FavoriteEnroledTrainee(SessionMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'here'
favorite_enroled_trainee = dajaxice_register(method='GET', name='company.favorite')(FavoriteEnroledTrainee.as_view())
```